# Crystal Reports not show into add new items in VS 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2015, crystal-reports, report

i have installed VS 2012 (Ultimate Edition) and VS 2015 (Enterprises Edition) both into my PC. Also installed crystal reports Sp 16.
crystal reports not show into add new items VS 2012.
[VS2012](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/74399858/vs2012.png)

but in VS2015 it shows
[VS2015](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/74399858/vs2015.png)

i m using Windows 10.
change .NetFramework 4.0 for both VS2012 and VS2015.
add appropriate referances for crystal reports into projects.
Crystal Reports show into toolbox in both VS2012 and VS2015.
all of these are 64 bits.

i have no idea about this.
please tell me what is the problem with VS2012.
Thanks in Advance.